# How to get the dispatch_async running

Tags: ios, objective-c, grand-central-dispatch, dispatch

In the below code, on running the app, the log inside the block variable

```
block1
```

Is never got executed, only the

```
NSLog(@"Delay_Expired");
```

Please let me know how to get the `dispatch_async` running.

**main**

```
dispatch_block_t block1 = ^{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval: 700];
        NSLog(@"current i = %d", i);
    }
};
dispatch_queue_t defaultPriority = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
dispatch_queue_t backgroundPriority = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0);
NSLog(@"Delay_Expired");

dispatch_async(defaultPriority, block1);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is running, but it’s running asynchronously, and you are simply exiting your app before it has a chance to finish. If you try this in a GUI app that stays alive until the user manually quits, you’ll see it behave like you expected.

If you’re doing this in a command line app, you can use dispatch groups to wait for the dispatched code to finish, e.g.:

```
dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();

dispatch_queue_t defaultPriority = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);

dispatch_group_async(group, defaultPriority, ^{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.7];
        NSLog(@"current i = %d", i);
    }
});

NSLog(@"Waiting");

dispatch_group_wait(group, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);

NSLog(@"All done");
```

You don’t generally do this in most GUI apps, but if you really want your command line app to wait for the dispatched code to finish, this will do the job.

---

By the way, are you aware that [`sleepForTimeInterval`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsthread/1413673-sleepfortimeinterval?language=occ) uses seconds, not milliseconds? Perhaps you intended to use 0.7 seconds, not 700 seconds?

Answer (score 1):

On the assumption that "**main**" means the `main()` startup function and the code you show is the whole body of `main()` then:

As soon as `main()` returns the app is terminated. So in your case `block1` may or may not start executing but the app quickly terminates regardless.

Copy your lines into the `applicationDidFinishLaunching:` (macOS) or `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` (iOS) methods of a standard GUI app and then run that. A GUI app as a run loop which keeps it running until some event terminates the app so your app will run long enough for your `block1` to execute (you might want to change the `700` to say `7` for the test or you'll be waiting a long time for it to finish).

HTH